# How to get table field list from ZEND SQL even if data not exist

Tags: sql, zend-framework, zend-db

I looking for **table field list** from the **SQL** even if data not exist...

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    tbl1 
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl2 
ON 
    tbl1.p_id = tbl2.f_id
```

optional : **ZEND DB**

Comment: You've tagged multiple RDBMS - please remove any tags not related to your question.

Comment: Query seems perfect to me. Could you please give an example of your needs.

Comment: looking for table field list from the sql...

Comment: for which RDBMS?

Comment: SQL... @Ermenegildo

Comment: `SQL` is just the query language. `MySQL` is a RDBMS, or `SQL Server`, `Oracle`, `Postgre`, and so on..

Comment: SQL SERVER......